# Bash - multiple nested quotes

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

How can i solve that kind of multiple nested quotes?

this is an example of the command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("bash -c \" echo cat /etc/passwd|grep ?root? \" ")}'
```

I tried with \' but it does not work..:

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("bash -c \" echo cat /etc/passwd|grep \'root\' \" ")}'
```

Comment: Is the command only for testing nested quotes or what so you want to achieve? Please [edit] your question to clarify this. The shell `echo` could be replaced with an AWK `print` or `printf`. The `grep` patern will be found anywhere in the line, this might not be what you want.

Comment: A couple of different suggestions that might point you in the right direction  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528238/how-do-i-use-awks-single-quotes-within-another-single-quote-phrase   https://superuser.com/questions/1239295/how-to-wrap-this-output-in-quotes   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593212/awk-print-apostrophe-single-quote

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include a `'` in a `'`-delimited string in shell, including in scripts, even when you try to escape it. There are options but the one that works for command-line tool scripts or tool scripts stored in files is to use `\047` wherever you need a `'`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("bash -c \" echo cat /etc/passwd|grep \047root\047 \" ")}'
```

See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

It's not clear why you'd write `cat /etc/passwd|grep 'root'` instead of `grep 'root' /etc/passwd` or what the `echo` is for but I assume you're just using it here to test quotes.

Comment: The actual comand is more complex than a cat /etc/passwd|grep, but it relies on echo and on the same logic, so yes, is just to test quotes. saldy with awk 'BEGIN{system("bash -c \"echo cat /etc/passwd|grep \047root\047 \"")}' does not produce any output...

Comment: Right, it wouldn't because `echo cat /etc/passwd|grep \047root\047` tells bash to run `echo cat /etc/passwd`  then pipe the output of that echo, which is **the string** `cat /etc/passwd`, to `grep root` but `root` doesn't exist in the string `cat /etc/passwd`. Running `echo cat /etc/passwd|grep 'root'` on the command line wouldn't produce any output so of course it won't when embedded in some other command. [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] to show us exactly what you're trying to do and that we can copy/paste to test with.`

Answer (score 1):

## Nesting quote and double quotes 3 different ways

### First *common* way: escaping double quotes:

```
awk "BEGIN{system(\"bash -c 'cat /etc/passwd|grep \\\"root\\\" ' \" )}"
```

You have to consider [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) preparing command line for `awk`. Escape double quotes, then instruct awk to escape double quotes... But this could become quickly confusing!

### Second way using *variable* AND *Inline script*:

```
read -r awkScript <<eoScript
  BEGIN{system("bash -c 'cat /etc/passwd|grep \"root\" ' " )}
eoScript
```

Then

```
awk "$awkScript"
```

I find this more *readable*!

### Third way, using *octal* values of characters:

Using `$'` and single quotes for enclosing string, every *single-quotes* have to be replaced by octal value: `\047` (or `\47`), and *backslashes* have to be escaped too (`\\`).

```
awk $'BEGIN{system("bash -c \47cat /etc/passwd|grep \\"root\\" \47" )}'
```

By using octal values, you could represent near everything you want!

Comment: @jagghy Why did you retract your accept choice?  Is there something wrong?